# AngularJS directive testing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to test the following directive.

```
angular.module('myModule.directives', [])
  .directive('test', function() {
    return {
      restrictions: 'E',
      scope: {},
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      template: '<div><ui><li>a</li></ul></div>'
    }
});
```

In my test:

```
describe('directives', function () {
    var compile,
    scope,
    test;

    beforeEach(module('myModule.directives'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {

    compile = $compile;
    scope = $rootScope;
    test = angular.element('<test></test>');
    compile(test)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    it('should render the test directive', function () {
        var lis = test.find('li');
        console.log(lis.length); // should output 1
    });

}));
```

Test fails and outputs 0. I am curious as to whether compile is actually doing anything. If I replace test with

```
  test = angular.element("<test><li></li></test>");.
```

Then the 'find' does find the li within the test element, which goes to show that compile is not rendering to

```
  '<div><ui><li>a</li></ul></div>'
```

as it should. Any ideas? I looked at the following vid for guidance (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB5b67Cg6bc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change "restrictions" to "restrict"

Comment: I never realized that mistake. That didn't fix it. I also tried outputting to a variable like you initially commented.

Comment: @aaron Did you take a look at the plunkr I made?

Comment: Thanks for setting up that example. When I figure out why it doesn't work in my environment, I'll post here. Thanks again.